# rvalue definition is objects that cannot be assigned values, but why are literals lvalues?

Tags: c, literals, lvalue, rvalue

So i'm reviewing in advanced our upcoming topics and I've come accross lvalues and rvalues, although the definition confuses me. Why is a literal an lvalue?

"rvalue refers to a data value that is stored at some address in memory. An rvalue is an expression that cannot have a value assigned to it"

"The original definition of lvalue referred to "an object that can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment." However, const objects are lvalues, and yet they cannot appear on the left-hand side of an assignment."

Comment: Aside from anything else, the C standard doesn't use the term "rvalue". Mixing terminology from different languages is bound to lead to confusion.

Comment: @Vincent - When the terminology was initially invented, C didn't have `const`. Is that an acceptable explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three categories of non-assignable lvalues in C: `const` objects, arrays (and objects with members that are const or array) and expressions with incomplete type.

String literals are arrays (by which I mean: the object to which a string literal expression refers is an array). That makes them lvalues.

Informally, an lvalue is an expression that refers to an object, and a string literal is an object.

---

If you want the formal definition of an lvalue in C, refer to the standard. In C99(6.3.2.1):

> An *lvalue* is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type
>   other than void; if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, 
>   the behavior is undefined.

with a footnote:

> The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression E1
>   = E2,in which the left operand E1 is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an object
>   ‘‘locator value’’

So appearing on the LHS of an assignment has nothing to do with it, other than the fact that lvalue used to mean something else, in some language other than standard C.

You might think that by that formal definition an integer constant `5` should also be an lvalue expression: it is an expression (specifically a primary-expression), and it has an object type (`int` is an object type). It's certainly valid to evaluate the expression `5`, so if it's an lvalue then it must "designate an object".

This would contradict the definition of the address-of operator, which says that its operand may be an lvalue expression that designates an object. Compilers reject `&5`, generally with an error message saying that `5` is *not* an lvalue.

I think the answer lies in 6.5.1, which lists the different types of primary-expression, including constants. For each of the other kinds of primary-expression it says under what conditions it is an lvalue. For constants it conspicuously says nothing, indicating that they aren't lvalues. But usually in the C standard, text of the form "An *X* is...", with *X* italicised, is a definition of the term X. So I think the standard could be clearer.

Update: the text in n1570 (a late draft of C11) is, with my emphasis added:

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) **that
>   potentially designates an object**

And the equivalent text in C89 (3.2.2.1) says "that designates an object" [thanks hvd]. This suggests to me that the authors of the standard aren't happy with the text either. A constant doesn't potentially designate an object, so under this definition numeric constants certainly are *not* lvalues.

Comment: `5` has object type, but is not an object, it is a value. "object" is defined as "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values".

Comment: @hvd: exactly. So 6.3.2.1 shouldn't (IMO) define an lvalue to be "an expression with an object type", because constants are expressions with object type.

Comment: 6.3.2.1 used to read "An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
designates an object", which was wrong for other reasons. The right wording appears to be very hard to find. (I think I got this the wrong way around, and you had the old definition. Either way, both are wrong in different ways.)

Answer (score 1):

An *informal* definition of an lvalue is basically any expression that can refer to an object (in the C sense, anything that takes up memory) such that the object's value may be read or modified.  Anything you could *potentially* apply the unary `&` operator to is an lvalue.

Unfortunately, you have some expressions that can refer to objects in memory, but the semantics are such that you cannot modify that object's value through that expression.  This includes array expressions (including string literals), expressions of `const`-qualified type, and expressions with incomplete type.

An example of the last type is something like the following:

```
struct foo;
struct foo *fooptr;
```

The expression `*fooptr` is an expression with an incomplete type; `struct foo` has not yet been fully defined.

So we have *modifiable* and *non-modifiable* lvalues.  A *modifiable* lvalue may be the target of an assignment.

String literals are *non-modifiable* lvalues by virtue of being array type expressions (string literals are stored as arrays of `char` such that the memory is visible to the entire program, and is held from program startup until termination, and the semantics of arrays are such that array expressions may not be the target of an assignment).  This is a distinct situation from *numeric* literals or individual character constants, which do not refer to items in memory.

Answer (score 0):

rvalues are defined as things that have no name or **which you cannot take the address of** or temporaries.

The original definition is no longer valid these days.  You can take the address of lvalues, but not of rvalues, which for me is the easiest distinction to make.

If you can't take the address of it, then it's an rvalue.

Comment: but it said "constants" are lvalues, aren't constants considered literals?

Comment: @vincentbelkin All literals are constants, but not all constants are literals.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so what are constants that are lvalues'

Comment: In the C standard, numbers like `1`, `0L` and `4.5` aren't referred to as literals, they're referred to as constants (and they aren't lvalues). I think in most languages (certainly including C++), they're referred to as literals (and still aren't lvalues).

Comment: @vincentbelkin I think you meant "constants that are *not* lvalues". These are, for example, named constants, e.g. `const int x = 123;` In this case, `x` is a constant; it cannot be assigned, yet it is not a literal (`123` is a literal, but `x` is not).